# jQuery ajaxStart & ajaxComplete live?

Tags: jquery

I have the following working just fine:

```
$(".new_comment").ajaxStart(function() {
    ajaxBanner('show');
    // Disable button
    $("input[type=submit]", this).attr("disabled", true);
});
$(".new_comment").ajaxComplete(function() {
    ajaxBanner('hide');
    // Re-enable button
    $("input[type=submit]", this).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Problem is that only works if the page renders with the comment form. In many cases the comment form is dynamically injected on the page, and this then fails.

How can I make the above live()?

thanks

Comment: you can check if "commentform" exists befor edoing any logic right.

Comment: got it , when you insert dynamically this is not working ok , then live should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't tested, but perhaps worth a try?

```
$(".new_comment").live("ajaxComplete", function() {
    ajaxBanner('show');
    // Disable button
    $("input[type=submit]", this).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

The alternative is to add the event when you dynamically inject the comment form, but we'll need some more of your code for that (i.e. where the injection happens).

Comment: ya AJAX is stil working great. I should add, I have multiple comment forms on the page, and sometimes inject new ones.. Here is what the form tag looks like: <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/conversations/65/comments" class="new_comment" data-remote="true" id="new_comment" method="post">

Comment: ok I was able to get it to work by wrapping theajaxComplete stuff inside of a form : $(".new_comment").live("submit",function(){

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how `.ajaxComplete()` works when binding to a jQuery selection, but I reckon you could solve your problem easily by binding to an element you know exists, i.e. `document`, and then using normal selectors:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    ajaxBanner('show');
    // Disable button
    $(".new_comment input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", true);
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
    ajaxBanner('hide');
    // Re-enable button
    $(".new_comment input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```